# Errors in the high-level relational engine. SQLServer Data Tools SSDT

Tags: sql-server, data

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>AnalisisCubo</DatabaseID>
        <CubeID>DW Northwind2</CubeID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
    Procesando Dimensión, 'DW Time' completados.
        Hora de inicio: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Hora de finalización: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Duración: 0:00:00
        Procesando Atributo de dimensión, '(All)' completados.
            Hora de inicio: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Hora de finalización: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Duración: 0:00:00
        Procesando Atributo de dimensión, 'Month' completados.
            Hora de inicio: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Hora de finalización: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Duración: 0:00:00
        Procesando Atributo de dimensión, 'Year' completados.
            Hora de inicio: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Hora de finalización: 10-06-2019 15:56:30; Duración: 0:00:00
Errores y advertencias de respuesta
    Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
    Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
    The following system error occurred: 
    Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DW Northwind2', Name of 'DW Northwind2'.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'DW Time', Name of 'DW Time' was being processed.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Month' attribute of the 'DW Time' dimension from the 'AnalisisCubo' database was being processed.
```

Hola tengo este error, estoy realizando un ejercicio en SQLServerDataTools (SSDT), ya hice mi base de datos de forma estrella, y cuando le doy proceso en el cubo olap me da este error, ya modifique la base de datos y nada, confirme que estén funcionando los servicios de SQL (ademas reinicie los servicios) y tambieen lo intenten ejecutanto el SSDT en modo administrador y no entiendo, tambien habilite en el SQLServerManangementStudio en la carpeta Security/Login si le negaba el acceso pero nada. ya no entiendo que otra configuracion hay que hacer para que ejecute el cubo olap.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿El SSDT es de 32  o 64 bits? Ese error se podría dar con un SSDT de 32 bits pero ejecutando el cubo en 64 bits. Si este fuera el caso podrías proba instalar el SSDT 64 bits o cambiar la ejecución de 64 bits en las propiedades del proyecto.

Comment: aaaaaaaaah no lo habia pensado, probare mucha gracias

Comment: ¿Lograste generar el cubo?

Comment: no, mi pc es 64 bit ps no intente mas, cuando pueda probare